# Breeze, CreateEntity with cloning existing enity

Tags: breeze

I have a need to clone existing entity and insert it as a new object to the database.

Can somebody please advise a best way accomplish this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have put that thing on hold for now. I should have something working by the end of this week and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I used detachEntity method of a breeze for the object I wanted to clone. However that left navigation property blank. I did not went through further research and wrote a generic code to manually copy the navigation properties to cloned object.

Cloned object then added to the breeze manager using createEnttiy and that did the job.